# Fastest way to download files in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, curl, wget

I'm trying to download a PDF file from an external website on a Ubuntu server.

My script is running in Node.js and it is important that the download is completed as fast as possible.

**The file should just be saved straight to the disk.** I have found two ways of achieving this...

1. Using Node's bult-in `http` library like in the following example.

   ```
   let file = fs.createWriteStream(path)
   http.get(url, response => response.pipe(file))
   ```
2. Calling `wget` using Node's `child_process` library like below. I am also aware that there are other commands like `curl` that could alternatively be used.

   ```
   exec('wget -P ' + path + ' ' + url)
   ```

I am aware that these examples may be bad coding but are just for illustration. I have also read that people often prefer using Node's `http` as it is not using any external libraries so is nicer.

However, **I am only concerned about speed**. My question is which is the fastest way to download a file?

I have been looking at https://www.hacksparrow.com/using-node-js-to-download-files.html which suggests that `wget` is the fastest solution but I am unsure how this conclusion has been reached.

Also, are there any downsides (apart from speed) to any of the methods? Are there any other ways to do this I haven't included?

Thanks!

Comment: i mean... the #1 contender of speed in your case will be network related... which all methods will be governed by. #2 would be disk io, which again will affect all methods.

Comment: You're right - however I am on a fast network connection. I suppose I'm also interested in which process is going to use the least memory.

Comment: Also, I am unsure as to why my question has been downvoted. Could people please explain how I can improve it before doing so?

Comment: Me telling you i find your question to be not useful and poorly researched isn't going to help you improve it.

Comment: If you're concerned about memory usage (is that even related to speed?) look into how each method uses memory to perform the action.

Comment: @KevinB _"Me telling you i find your question to be not useful and poorly researched isn't going to help you improve it."_ There is a possibility that it could?

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for your help. Perhaps I have slightly mislead you - my primary concern is speed however your comment made me think that memory was also something to consider. To address your point about research in my question, I have just amended it to include a link to an article that prompted me to ask this question.

Comment: The purpose of the downvote wasn't to help you improve the question. It's a signal to everyone else that this question isn't useful and they should move on.

Comment: @Zak What do you mean by "Fastest"? What is the time of current approach? Not sure how a method could be faster than streaming directly to file location at server?

Comment: @guest271314 I am currently using Python but am migrating my application to JS so I don't really have anything to compare to. I simply mean shortest time to download to disk - which method would streaming be?

Comment: _"which method would streaming be?"_ ? The `javascript` approach which you included at your Question `let file = fs.createWriteStream(path)
http.get(url, response => response.pipe(file))`? Your responses at comments are proving @KevinB sense to be correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 And why is that? The article I linked to stated that `wget` would be faster. I understand that the situation is not black and white but it would be helpful if you could outline some of the things to consider?

Comment: My point basically was any optimization you make in this case is going to be extremely minor in the grand scheme of things. It isn't worth worrying over, use the method that makes the most sense for your usecase.

Comment: The first item to consider when asking about "fastest" would be to have actually benchmarked your current implementation.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the answer - I'd be happy to accept that if you make it into an answer. Sorry you haven't found my question useful but it certainly is for me and I'm sure there will be others who think the same thing.

Comment: @guest271314 It's more of a theoretical question. Also, as I stated, I want to understand the other effects of different approaches as well (such as memory). That's something benchmarking won't tell me if I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: The Question does not involve quantum mechanics. Generally, time is measurable, and not theoretical. There currently are no "different approaches" to measure against, as you have not measured what you are currently implementing. Benchmark the entire process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to network and io limitations, there is no reason to choose a method in your case based on "speed". The download speed and write speed is out of your control (programmatically), leaving just the speed of the individual methods themselves. Since networks and io have a maximum speed, using the method that executes fastest isn't important because said method will ultimately be throttled by the network and/or io anyway once you start looking at downloading multiple files.

Use the method that makes more sense for the situation. In your case, if you're trying to download files with node, it makes more sense to me to use node.js to do it rather than wget with a child process.